# mongorestore error: Don't know what to do with the dump file

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have mongo DB installed in the following path `c:\mongodb\bin`. I have configured my environment variable PATH in advanced settings.I also have mongod running .When I run the following command **mongorestore dump** from the following path `c:\hw1-1\dump` (This contains the BSON files) I'm getting this error:

> Don't know what to do with the dump file

I have referred to [this thread](https://education.mongodb.com/courses/10gen/M101JS/2014_January/discussion/forum/i4x-10gen-M101JS-course-2014_January/threads/52d7b1cdabcee8bd1e006540) to check my path.

Comment: All the answers are different because all this error really means is that some of your flags are incorrect. Which flags are incorrect will depend on what your restoring and where your restoring it. Use `mongodump --help` to get a list of the current flags on your instance to debug this issue.

Answer (score 351, accepted):

in mongodb 3.0 or above, we should specify the database name to restore

```
mongorestore -d [your_db_name] [your_dump_dir]
```

Comment: I am using windows version 3.0.3 and specifying the database name did it for me!Thank you @clevertension.

Comment: Worked like a charm on 3.0.6 too.

Comment: This was the issue I had after upgrading `mongodb-tools`, thanks!

Comment: This worked for me using authentication like so: `mongorestore -u k00k -p 1337p455w0rd -d mydb ./dump/mydb`

Comment: This is an old answer. In newer versions you cannot specify the `--db` (`-d`) parameter in many cases. This is how I restore it currently:
`mongorestore --nsFrom=fromdbname.* --nsTo=todbname.* yourdumpfolder/`
Furtherly when you used gzip you need to provide the `--gzip` parameter and if you want to override stuff you can add the `--drop` parameter.

Comment: mongorestore mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27017/ dump/

Folder structure should be 
/dump/<databasename>
<file>.json
<file>.bson

Answer (score 38):

You probably saw this error:

> ERROR: don't know what to do with file [dump]

Which means in this case, that there is no file or directory called `dump` in your current working directory. So, Try this first `cd c:/hw1-1/` (or whatever the correct syntax is on Windows, I can't test it.) Alternatively you can specify the full path to the `dump` directory:

```
mongorestore c:/hw1-1/dump
```

Comment: thank you c:/hw1-1 mongorestore dump works fine ..

Comment: This command in combination with the uri connection string did the trick for me.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using `mongoexport` to create the dump, be sure to use `mongoimport` rather than `mongorestore` to load it.

Comment: yeah, this was the magic wand for me since i used `mongoexport`. tnx

Answer (score 6):

This error message "don't know what to do with file" can also occur if you have a BSON file that does not have a .bson file extension.

Generally this isn't a problem since `mongodump` generates the files with .bson extensions, but in my case I had a BSON file that was not generated by `mongodump` and had a different file extension.

Comment: and how do you restore file without .bson extension? (.rdb in my case)

Comment: I get this unhelpful error on files *with* the `.bson` extension: `don't know what to do with file "dump/mydb/users.bson", skipping...`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I used --gzip for my mongodump but didn't use it for my mongorestore

Answer (score 5):

I'm on `version 3.2 windows` and my `mongorestore` seems to have a bug:

If I specify `/db:database_name` or `/d database_name` I get the error:

```
don't know what to do with subdirectory "dump\database_name", skipping...
```

Instead if I let it run on the whole dump directory it seems to work. The command I used is:

`mongorestore /host:remote_host dump`

My current directory structure is:

```
.
..
dump
dump\database_name
```

Comment: Love you man, I just needed to add an extra directory on top and that worked lol

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I had a collection matching the name of the one I was trying to restore present in Mongo ended up going into Mongo and deleting it using db.m101.drop();

Answer (score -1):

It took me some time to figure out the options for mongorestore , after i had kept getting this error for some time .

a) No running instances of mongod .

b) `mongorestore -v -host localhost:27017 --dbpath "Actual Path for the Mongo DB- set in config" "Location where the dump is"`

Using dbpath , allows to run this command without any running version of mongod .
And this resolved my error .