# mongorestore file X does not have .bson extension

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to run mongorestore through docker to restore the database to another dockerized mongo on the system:

```
sudo docker run --net=host -v $PWD:/home/mongo mongo /bin/bash -c "mongorestore -d venko /home/mongo/mongo_venko_20200326230306.archive"
```

but I get

```
2020-03-27T00:17:32.645+0000    the --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from a BSON file. Other uses are deprecated and will not exist in the future; use --nsInclude instead
2020-03-27T00:17:32.645+0000    Failed: file /home/mongo/mongo_venko_20200326230306.archive does not have .bson extension
2020-03-27T00:17:32.645+0000    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

Answers from [mongorestore error: Don't know what to do with the dump file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233290/mongorestore-error-dont-know-what-to-do-with-the-dump-file) tell me to pass the -db option but I did pass so I don't know what to do.

Comment: try passing the file with `--archive=<filename>`

Comment: @Joe it worked. Thanks. For anyone reading, this bash script restores a file from mongodump using docker: `sudo docker run --net=host -v $PWD:/home/mongo mongo /bin/bash -c "mongorestore --archive=/home/mongo/$1"`

Answer (score 15):

I have to use both options **--gzip** and **--archive**

```
mongorestore --uri="uri" --gzip --archive=/Path/to/archive/abc.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error mentions the mongorestore looks for a BSON file, while the archive is not the extension it is looking for.

You can do the following:

1. Either use:

   mongorestore --gzip /home/mongo/mongo_venko_20200326230306.archive
2. Or, Extract the archive file and use:

   mongorestore /home/mongo/mongo_venko_20200326230306/<filename.bson>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command

```
mongorestore --archive=<path to *.archive> <database name>
```

for instance

```
mongorestore --archive=/home/mmroshani/mongo_gps_mongo_20230405-130054.archive gps
```

The correct output is kinda like

```
...

2023-04-07T14:01:18.397+0330    26868024 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

This fixed the issue and worked well, hope it helps and thanks for your consideration.