# How can I restore from .dump file on ubuntu using mongorestore?

Tags: mongodb

```
/home/ubuntu/atlas-db.dump
```

I have this directory of dump files. I want to import this data to my localhost mongodb with the db name of 'testingg'. I've tried like all sort of stuffs that I can find to restore. like nsInclude or --db (which is depreciated).

So far, nothing has worked. How can I copy that `atlas-db.dump` file with all my collections from atlas to my localhost mongodb `testingg` on Ubuntu?

Comment: Hoping this will helps you...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233290/mongorestore-error-dont-know-what-to-do-with-the-dump-file

Comment: If you tried everything and nothing works, there is nothing left to help. Please be more specific - what command did you try and what error did you get. Also what versions of the databases? In context of https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-2577