# mongorestore: don't know what to do with subdirectory "dump/mydb", skipping

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore, mongodb-tools

I have taken a `mongodump` of a specific db from a Mongo cluster as follows:

```bash
mongodump mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@mongo-uri/mydb
```

This created a `dump/mydb` directory.

Now I am trying to restore it to another Mongo cluster more or less as follows

```bash
mongorestore mongodb+srv://<new_username>:<new_password>@new-mongo-uri/mydb
```

The process fails with

```
don't know what to do with subdirectory "dump/mydb", skipping...
```

I have also [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29640961/2409793)

```
mongorestore mongodb+srv://<new_username>:<new_password>@new-mongo-uri -d mydb
```

same result

How is the correct format for the command?

Comment: What happens with `mongorestore 'mongodb+srv://<new_username>:<new_password>@new-mongo-uri/' --nsInclude='mydb.*' dump/`?